# Highcharts, How to remove gaps on x coordinates

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

**For a Highcharts spline type chart, I want to completely remove the left and right spaces.**

I tried to change some options but there is no success.
Spacing and margin keys did not make any appearance changes.

Does anyone have any info on how to remove the spaces, all help is welcome.

[Example chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEp7c.png)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  chart: {
    type: 'spline',
  },
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [7, 13, 16, 18, 19, 20, 29, 22, 25, 38, 23, 26, 28, 29, 33],
  },
  yAxis: {
    tickPosition: 'inside',
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    floor: 0,
    tickWidth: 1
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
  }, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

These gaps are added when using the xAxis.categories option. If you remove these options then it works the way you want. For tick positioning in this case it is better to set other available API options. Find out more about it here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions